# How to Know if you are connected to Wifi Hotspot/Wifi/ Wifi Direct

Tags: android, wifi, wifi-direct

Is there any way in Android we can figure out that if we are already CONNECTED to some Wifi or Wifi Direct or Hotspot.

if yes please let me know how? I need to find for all the 3(wifi/hotspot/wifi direct) and based on the answer do something in my application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a code snap hope it will work for you !

```
public static int getNetworkType(Context context) {
    ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    if (connectivity != null) { 
        // 获取网络连接管理的对象
        NetworkInfo info = connectivity.getActiveNetworkInfo();

        if (info != null && info.isConnected()) {
            // 判断当前网络是否已经连接
            if (info.getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
                if (info.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("WIFI")) {
                    return MrDefines.NETTYPE_WIFI;
                } else {
                    Cursor mCursor = context.getContentResolver().query(
                            Uri.parse("content://telephony/carriers"), 
                            new String[] {"name"}, "current=1", 
                            null, null);

                    if(mCursor != null && mCursor.moveToFirst()){
                        String name = mCursor.getString(0);
                        mCursor.close();

                        if(name.equalsIgnoreCase("cmnet"))
                            return MrDefines.NETTYPE_CMNET;
                        else if(name.equalsIgnoreCase("cmwap"))
                            return MrDefines.NETTYPE_CMWAP;
                    }else if (mCursor != null) {
                        mCursor.close();
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }

    return MrDefines.NETTYPE_UNKNOW;
}
```

Comment: Do not care it, it's the definition of connection type

Answer (score 0):

I think WifiManager and ConnectivityManager could be the things You need. Look at the references

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html